# Adding neo4j-spatial dependency causes error

Tags: maven, neo4j, apache-pivot

I have a project that includes, among others, Apache Pivot and Neo4j. My project compiles and runs. When I try to add Neo4j/Spatial:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>neo4j-spatial</artifactId>
  <version>0.11-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

The project compiles but will not run. The compiler sources the error at one of the BXML files:

```
org.apache.pivot.serialization.SerializationException: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.imageio.spi.ImageOutputStreamSpi: Provider com.sun.media.imageioimpl.stream.ChannelImageOutputStreamSpi could not be instantiated: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: vendorName == null!
```

I can't understand how adding a dependency can break the project at runtime. I did not change any code. I'll post whatever code is necessary as asked.

**UPDATE**: I've tried a previous, stable version with the same result. Also, I've added "vendor" and version information to my jar manifest that seems to fix the vendorName == null error and causes the project to hang on close rather than open. But my question, which I'll rephrase here, is the same.

How does adding a dependency, without changing code, cause a functioning project to fail at runtime? I don't understand how adding the dependency changes the execution if I don't call it.

Comment: Does it also happen with the latest stable version (0.10.1)?

Comment: No, where can I get that? I got 0.11-SNAPSHOT from cloning the git rep.

Comment: Check http://m2.neo4j.org/content/repositories/releases/org/neo4j/neo4j-spatial/. You can add the repository to your maven repositories list.

Comment: Got a link to how to do that?

Comment: Yes, https://www.google.com/search?q=maven%20repositories. ;-) Add the `<repositories>` element to your pom

Comment: <repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>neo4j.org</id>
 <url>http://m2.neo4j.org/content/repositories/releases/org/neo4j/neo4j-spatial/
</url>
 </repository>
</repositories>
Does not work

Comment: Of course not. You need the repository URL, not the entire path that points to a single dependency. Try "http://m2.neo4j.org/content/repositories/releases".

Comment: Are you referring to the fact that the dependency is not retrieved from the repository or to the fact that you're getting the same exception as in your original question?

Comment: Dependency is resolved, original exception.

Comment: Pretty clueless actually. Hopefully someone of the Neo4j team will take a look at this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be issues with versioning. If you add a dependency, and you have another library which has the same dependency but a different version, the usual behaviour of Maven is for the latest version to be imported, and occasionally that can break the code that depended on the old version, due to a changed interface or whatever.

So if A depends on B v1, and C depends on Bv2, then when you add C, it overwrites Bv1 with Bv2 in the effective POM, which in theory could break it.

I am sure that there is a way around this, but I am not an expert with Maven. SO check your effective POM for changes to versions when you import the new thing.